# What do you call text/information which cannot be found in Google?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a special word for not being able to Google something? For instance, I have a quote from a book, but if I look up it in Google I won't find any information about this quote, as it was never published in the Internet or Google didn't index it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a special word, you can use *ungoogleable*:

["Who, What, Why: What is 'ungoogleable'?"](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-21956743)

I dislike the sound of this word and would opt for a phrase like, "it can't be found on the internet," or one of the many words that mean *difficult to find*, variously shaded (intentionally hidden, forgotten, ignored, etc.).